# How to get a straight bevel on a path?

Tags: extrude, path, bevel

I want to create a border for a window. The bevel object is a simple shape. The path isn't closed and has an opening at the bottom. Both vertex point has the same values on the x-axis. Also, the scale values are equal. But somehow I don't get a straight extrude. If I convert it to a mesh, the discrepancy stays the same. What's the problem with this?

[image: straight line, but uneven extude]